# How do I enable cors in $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, cors, angular-mock

I am using $httpBackend to supply data for an Angular application.  When the application was connected to a live server with cors enabled, it was working fine.  But now we want to put it back on the mock data to do additional UI development.  But when I run it the calls are being blocked by the browser (Chrome and Firefox).

This is what the server looks like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('autoApp.mocks').run(config);

    config.$inject = ['$httpBackend', '$httpProvider',
        'MockConfigRepository',
        'MockSearchRepository', 'MockSummaryRepository'];
    function config($httpBackend, $httpBackend, MockConfigRepository,
                    MockSearchRepository, MockSummaryRepository){


        $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/localhost.*/).passThrough();
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/autoApp.*/).passThrough();

        $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/mockServer\/api\/v1\.0\/contract\.aspx/)
            .respond(function (){
                var payload = MockConfigRepository.getPayload();
                return [200, payload, {}];
            });

            // and more calls like that 
    }
}());
```

My understanding is that cors has to be enabled on the server.  I have tried

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

and

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"};
```

but the browser is still blocking.

Can someone point me in the right direction?